# query only direct child and sub-terms of a current term archive

Tags: wp-query, archives, plugins, terms, children

i'm using woocommerce on my theme, and it comes with a proudct_cat term as a defualt catagory on the shop proudct.
I need to show on every proudct_cat archive its direct child and the sub-tems, but not the sub terms child.

I tried:

```
        <?php $thispage = $wp_query->post; wp_list_categories("taxonomy=product_cat&term=". $term->slug."&title_li=&child_of=".$thispage->slug);?>
```

and it returned all proudct_cat as ul and the sub-term of the archive im in, but not the archive's children.

I tried:

```
global $post;
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat');
        foreach ( $terms as $term )
        $currentID = get_the_ID();
        $args=array(
            'taxonomy'=>'product_cat',
            'term' => $term->slug,
            'child_of'=>$currentID
         );

        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    ?>

        <?php if ( $my_query->have_posts() ): ?>
        <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="booklink"><?php the_title();?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

and it returned all the the current archive's children and the sub-terms children without the sub-term it self.

So i tried :

```
        $term_id = $terms;
        $taxonomy_name = 'product_cat';
        $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
            $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
```

and it returned nothing.

I'm Speechless. anyone have a clue?

*sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0):

Try `get_terms( 'product_cat', 'parent=' . get_queried_object_id() )`

**Update:** Re-read your question, think I have a better idea:

```
<ul class="categories">
    <?php

        wp_list_categories(
            array(
                'child_of' => get_queried_object_id(),
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'title_li' => '',
                   'depth' => 2,
            )
        )

    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: got nothing....

Comment: Check out my update.

Comment: Ok, cool... but it returns only the current sub term.

Answer (score 0):

got an idea... if this returns only the sub term:
wp_list_categories( array('child_of' => get_queried_object_id(),'taxonomy' => 'product_cat','title_li' => '','depth' => 1, 'show_option_none'=> ''));

maybe i can exacude all of its children in a guery args and then call the wp_list_categories.
tried:
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat');
            foreach ( $terms as $term )
            $currentID = get_the_ID();
            $args=array(
                'taxonomy'=>'product_cat',
                'term' => $term->slug,
                'exclude '=> array('child_of' => get_queried_object_id())
             );
             $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );?>

but it returns only the sub-term children, not the the proudct_cat children...

Anyone?